# Modifying Project Dependency Programatically

Tags: c#

Is there a way to add project dependency programmatically? For some reason the project in my solution file the project dependency is not set. What I am thinking of

1. Open the file and load it as xml document
2. Traverse through the references . Get the names of the dependency
3. Get the guid of those project reference
4. Prepare the project dependency section element
5. Modify the file by adding this section
6. Do the same for other 60+ projects

If I am not wrong we can do this by using MSBUILD classes as well .
Any better suggestions ?

On the same line I need to modify the path of one dll in all these project . I don’t want to do it manually .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I wrote a utility which reads the csproj and sln file as string[] and using Loops/Linq updated the lines and then wrote it back System.IO

Also JetBrains and MSBuild engine has class to find the dependency of a project , what dll its refrerencing etc etc. 
If anyone needs help with this then let me know